# Property initializers in React classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I've started to see this pattern pop up:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // ...
  };

  //...
}
```

I thought this was invalid at first, till I looked it up and realized it was ES7. Is this a safe (i.e. future-proof) syntax to use? I ask because I realize not all syntaxes in ES6 and ES7 are approved, many are simply proposed. I do like this better than what I've been using:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

MyComponent.propTypes = { .. }
```

Comment: It is not safe, nothing in ES7 is set in stone. ES6 is the current standard, so all the syntax in ES6 is safe.

Comment: "all the syntax in ES6 is safe" - except for using rests in objects. `return {...state, otherStuff}`

Comment: Object spread is not ES6.

Comment: How are we supposed to keep track of what's official in each ECMAScript version?

Comment: ES6 is done, the spec is official, you can read it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). For future features, unless it is at least in stage-2 I wouldn't use it personally. The proposals for new features are usually found on github.

Comment: Wow.. just a light read. ;) There's not a more "digestible" version of that document?

Comment: It's not ES7, aka ES2016. ES7 has only two additions: `Array#includes` and the exponentiation operator (`**`). http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh And decorators.

Comment: No, not even close. Decorators are stage 1. https://github.com/tc39/ecma262

Comment: So all the articles mentioning “ES7 decorators” are inaccurate?

Comment: Yes. There's a lot of misuse of the term "ES7".

Comment: Interesting. Could you share a link that would clear this up?

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe and future-proof. Those features are part of [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf), not ES7, and it is already an approved standard.

Browsers have gotten pretty far in implementing these features, as seen in [this compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).